# How to show that $\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question in the title. I have big problems getting the $\sqrt{5} $ out of there. How do I show this algebraically?

Comment: You can't. That's not even true. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F(2%2Bsqrt(5))+-+1%2Fsqrt(2)

Comment: hmm strange. I got this out of an old trig textbook (very old). So I guess they made an error then.

Comment: Really? You input the question correctly right

Comment: [A better way to show the statement is false](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F(2%2Bsqrt(5))+%3D+1%2Fsqrt(2))

Comment: @suomynonA I wouldn't say that's better. You have no idea how close it is  and you have to trust that WA is interpreting equality properly.

Comment: The equality holds for certain values of $5$ only ;-) Yet another [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F(2%2Bsqrt(x))+%3D+1%2Fsqrt(2)) way to look at it, which gives a root at approx $5.0924...$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can algebraically show that this is false. Assume for the sake of contradiction that

$$\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Then

$$3\sqrt{2} = 2+\sqrt{5}$$

$$18 = 9+4\sqrt{5}$$

$$9 = 4\sqrt{5}$$

$$81 = 80$$

This is obviously a contradiction, finishing the proof.

Answer (score 2):

May be, the question was to show that $$\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}}\approx\frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ So, let $$\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2}}+x$$ Solve for $x$ to get, after some simplification, $$x=3 \sqrt{5}-6-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Using your pocket calculator, you should find $x\approx 0.0011$ which is effectively quite small when compared to $\frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.7071$.